# Serializing a large model with references for custom dsl performs poorly

Tags: performance, serialization, xtext

- Create a new xtext project with grammar below
- run the test snippet to generate a file
- note save is taking a long time, if I change output to xmi it saves very quick.

Model

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"
Model:
    'namespace' name=QualifiedName ';'
    statements+=Statement (statements+=Statement)*
    ;

QualifiedName:
    ID ('.' ID)*;   
Statement:
    (
    SystemThread 
    | FunctionalUseCase
    | Action
);

SystemThread :
    'thread' name=ID
    '{'
        ('functionals' ':' functionals+=[FunctionalUseCase] (',' functionals+=[FunctionalUseCase])* ';')?
        ('actions' ':' qualifyingActions+=[Action|QualifiedName] (',' qualifyingActions+=[Action|QualifiedName])* ';')?  
    '}';

FunctionalUseCase:
    'functional' name=ID
    '{'
        ('actions' ':' prerequisite+=[Action|QualifiedName] (',' prerequisite+=[Action|QualifiedName])* ';')?  
        ('functionals' ':' subfunctionals+=[FunctionalUseCase] (',' subfunctionals+=[FunctionalUseCase])* ';')? 

    '}';
Action :
    'action' name=ID
    '{'


    '}';
```

snippet

```java
public static void createBigModel()
    {
        Injector inj = new MyDslStandaloneSetupGenerated().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
        String theFile = "C:/data/big3.mydsl"; // if i chnage to xmi it saves quick
        File aFile = new File(theFile);
        if(aFile.exists())
        {
            aFile.delete();
        }
        XtextResourceSet myResourceSet = inj.getInstance(XtextResourceSet.class);
        URI uri = URI.createFileURI(theFile);
        Resource resource = myResourceSet.createResource(uri);

        org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.Model m = MyDslFactory.eINSTANCE.createModel();
        resource.getContents().add(m);
        m.setName("myglobals.foo.bar.test1");

        Action a1 = MyDslFactory.eINSTANCE.createAction();
        a1.setName("a1");
        m.getStatements().add(a1);

        Map<String,FunctionalUseCase> mfuncs = new HashMap<String,FunctionalUseCase>();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(int x=0;x<10000;++x)
        {
            FunctionalUseCase f1 = MyDslFactory.eINSTANCE.createFunctionalUseCase();
            f1.setName("f" + x);
            f1.getPrerequisite().add(a1);
            m.getStatements().add(f1);
            mfuncs.put(f1.getName(), f1);
        }
        for(int x=0;x<10000;++x)
        {
            SystemThread t1 = MyDslFactory.eINSTANCE.createSystemThread();
            t1.setName("thread" + x);
            //String fname = "f"+x;
            //t1.getFunctionals().add(mfuncs.get(fname));
            m.getStatements().add(t1);

        }
        long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        EcoreUtil.resolveAll(resource);
        System.out.println("Creation time = " + (end1-start));
        try
        {
            resource.save(null);    
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        long end2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Save time = " + (end2-end1));
    }
```

Comment: does your usecase target eclipse or standalone only

Comment: It targets both standalone (as part of a codegen fw) and eclipse for the editing experience.

Comment: In addtion I tried adding a IResourceScopeCache, but that only helped some things there is still something that seems to loop thru all the top level statements to resolve refs. ie. If i enabled the line t1.getFunctionals().add(mfuncs.get(fname)); the problem gets worse.

Comment: the main problem is the cross reference serialize (org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.tokens.CrossReferenceSerializer.getCrossReferenceNameFromScope(EObject, CrossReference, EObject, IScope, Acceptor))
and the way how it queries the scope and how that is not optimized.
depending on your logic you might be able to calculate the name to be serzialized without quering the scope.

Comment: i also recommend you to open a issue at github.com/eclipse/xtext-core